# RPATH must exist at compile time

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, rpath

Please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious here. I'm developing some applications for another platform, and all of my proprietary libraries are installed to /app/lib. To facilitate this, I specify a runtime library path for each of my binaries as "/app/lib". This works fine; however, it requires that the path "/app/lib" exist in my build environment when linking (even though that directory is empty). I'm using NetBeans, which might be complicating matters, but I can see "-Wl, -rpath /app/lib" being passed to gcc.

I'd like to avoid the need to create an empty "/app/lib" in my build environment, but I don't want to change the file structure on my target platform. If I delete /app/lib from the build environment, I get an error when building that it can't be found. Is there a way to specify a runtime search path without the need for it to exist at link time?

Comment: `-Wl, -rpath /app/lib` is an incorrect option spec, should be `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/app/lib` (maybe there are other ways, but this works and doesn't require the dir on the build host). Did you mis-copy your build option here?

Comment: I went back and double checked, but I've confirmed that the call is being built as "gcc -o ... -Wl,-rpath /app/lib ...". NetBeans is building this makefile, so if it's invalid, it might require a fix on their end. However, the build process does succeed if /app/lib exists in my build environment, and the resulting binary uses the path at runtime.

Comment: Strange... I though that didn't work. I'll see if I can repro later, seems a bit weird.

Comment: Mat is exactly right, the syntax should be "-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/app/lib" ("-Wl,-rpath,/app/lib" works too). This is a bug in NetBeans. The reason why it's not more critical (and why I didn't notice this before) is that link-time search paths appear to carry over into runtime. Because NetBeans isn't placing a comma between -rpath and /app/lib, /app/lib is being interpreted as a link-time search path. As a result, my dependent libraries are still found at run-time in the appropriate location, but because it's a link-time dependency, the linking fails because /app/lib doesn't exist.

Comment: Mat, if you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll give you credit for it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: And, for anyone who's interested in tracking this issue, here's the link to the NetBeans bug that I've created: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=210642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be "-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/app/lib" ("-Wl,-rpath,/app/lib" works too). This is a bug in NetBeans. The reason why it's not more critical (and why I didn't notice this before) is that link-time search paths appear to carry over into runtime. Because NetBeans isn't placing a comma between -rpath and /app/lib, /app/lib is being interpreted as a link-time search path. As a result, my dependent libraries are still found at run-time in the appropriate location, but because it's a link-time dependency, the linking fails because /app/lib doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think the option you are looking for is `-Wl,-rpath-link,/path/to/libraries`. You need to use *both* options at once.

The linker will then use `-rpath-link` to find the libraries at link-time, but it'll encode the `-rpath` value into the binary for use at run time.